# Relationship between minimizing mutual information and maximizing non-Gaussianity in Independent Component Analysis (ICA)

Tags: independence, information-theory, mutual-information, independent-component-analysis

In independent component analysis (ICA), we assume that the observe data $\bf{x}$ from $n$ channels come from linear mixing of $n$ independent sources $\bf{s}$:
$$
\bf{x}=\bf{As}
$$
And we try to find a matrix $\bf{W}$ so that the components in:
$$
\bf{u}=\bf{Wx}
$$
are statistically independent. This means that, in theory, we should minimize the mutual information between the components in $\bf{u}$.

However, some papers about ICA instead suggest that we can also do ICA by maximizing the non-Gaussianity of the components in $\bf{u}$ (for example, [Hyvarinen & Oja, Neural Network, 2000](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893608000000265)). While I understand that by Central Limit Theorem, distribution of sum of independent non-Gaussian random variables becomes more Gaussian, is there a formal mathematical proof that "maximizing the non-Gaussianity" is equivalent to "minimizing the mutual information"?